# Spring request scope bean not binding to same request in different DI instances

Tags: spring, scope, request, javabeans

I have a class A that I want to be a request scope bean in two other classes. 
In one class I write some data to the instance and in another class I attempt to read the data but it doesn't reference the same instance where the data is written even though it is in the same request.

My config is like this:

```
<bean name="blah" class="class.that.WritesToA">
   <property name="A" ref="A"/>
</bean>
<bean name="whatever" class="class.that.ReadsFromA">
   <property name="A" ref="A"/>
</bean>
<bean id="A" class="com.audit.Service" scope="request">
    <aop:scoped-proxy />
</bean>
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: How can you tell it's not the same instance?

Comment: In eclipse the id of the object is different when debugging.

Comment: Can you please provide a minimal example that we can use to reproduce the issue you are seeing? A simple bean autowired in a controller and some other bean, etc.